# Magento 2 Customer import fails

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, importexport

I had exported customer from local machine and i am importing on server. When i tried to import on server it gives me an error saying "Sorry, but the data is invalid or the file is not uploaded."

I have not changed anything on in the csv file, both database of live and local are same, only on local i have new customers.

Answer (score 0):

Download csv from live server & match its structure with local their should definitely difference between the structure of fies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the PHP version. We were running Magento 2.2.6 on PHP 7.2 version. I had to change certain line on code in vendor directory.

Comment: any chance you remember what you changed?